# duplicate key value violates unique constraint with on conflict is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, unique-index

I am trying to use on conflict with unique on multiple fields. I have this structure.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      name           |     string       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      field_a        |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      field_b        |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      field_c        |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

`field_a,field_b,field_c` are unique and `field_b` can be NULL.

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO table (field_a, field_b,field_c,  name) 
values ('434d1d67-df03-4310-b3eb-93bf1c6e319e',
        'd3a3745e-ad97-4fcd-1fed-26bb406dc265',
        'd5a4232e-ad56-6ecd-5fed-25bb106dc114')
on conflict(field_a,field_b,field_c) 
do update
  set  name = 'abc'
```

If I try this with same query again it works. It updates on conflict. But when I use null like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
table (field_a, field_b,field_c,  name) 
values ('434d1d67-df03-4310-b3eb-93bf1c6e319e',
        null,
        'd5a4232e-ad56-6ecd-5fed-25bb106dc114')
on conflict(field_a,field_b,field_c) 
do update
set  name = 'abc'
```

This does not work. This will add new row in my table. To prevent adding new row I created an index and set NULL values like this

```
CREATE 
UNIQUE INDEX uidx_uniq ON table USING btree (
   (COALESCE(field_a, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)),
   (COALESCE(field_a, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)),
   (COALESCE(field_a, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)))
```

This does not allow adding new value in db if any exists with null but on conflict does not work with this it gives me Error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uidx_uniq"
```

How can I resolve this with null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html) says:

> Null values are not considered equal.

So there is no conflict if one of the values is NULL.

You cannot use the unique index you created with the `ON CONFLICT` clause, because you can only use unique *constraints* there. Unique constraints cannot be defined on expressions, only on columns.

Perhaps you should use a different value that NULL so model what you mean. NULL means “unknown” in SQL, so PostgreSQL's interpretation makes sense.

Comment: Yes (if I understand correctly) but I am not considering null as "null" my null means "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000".

Comment: Then, by all means, use that value and not NULL. Then things will work as you want them to, and as a positive side effects, your queries may become simpler (and hence faster).

Comment: I have tried putting '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' instead of null it also does not works but if i put '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' instead of null it works.

Comment: Both value will work the same way. There must have been some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also want a filtered unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_uniq2 ON table (field_a, field_c)
    WHERE field_b IS NULL;
```

You'll need to check both indexes for conflicts in `ON CONFLICT`.